# Curse of dimensionality $2^d +1$ hyperspheres inside a hypercube

Tags: geometry, volume, machine-learning, spheres

Consider a $d-$dimensional hypercube $Q$ of side length $l ∈ R, i. e. |x_i − y_i
| ≤ l$ for all
$x, y ∈ Q$ and all $i ∈ [d]$. Note that $Q$ has $2^d$
corners. We fill $Q$ with ($L_2-)$hyperballs the
following way:

1. We place 2d hyperballs of radius $\frac{l}{4}$ close to the $2^d$
   corners of $Q$, such that their distance to the center of  $Q$ is maximal while still being completely contained in $Q$.
2. We place an additional single hyperball in the center of $Q$ such that its radius is
   maximal with the property that it intersects with none of the other hyperballs’
   intereriors.

What is the minimal dimension d such that the the surface of the central hyperball peeks
trough the surface of Q?

I was thinking about computing the volume, but things got very complicated, as i could not found the lower bound for the dimension $d$.

I would appreciate any ideas that could make it easier for me to solve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may as well set $l=1$ and talk about the unit hypercube.  The hyperspheres in the corners then had diameter $\frac 12$.  Consider the body diagonal of the hypercube.  It goes through the centers of two of the corner hyperspheres, the center of the center hypersphere, and two of the points of tangency between the center hypersphere and corner hyperspheres.

[image]

The length of the body diagonal is $\sqrt d$.  The distance from the corner of the hypercube to the center of a corner hypersphere is $\sqrt{\frac d{16}}=\frac {\sqrt d}4$.  The distance from the corner of the hypercube to a tangency point is then $\frac {\sqrt d+1}4$.  The radius of the central hypersphere is then $\frac {\sqrt d}2-\frac{\sqrt d+1}4$.  The central hypersphere touches the face of the hypercube when this is $\frac 12$
$$\frac {\sqrt d}2-\frac{\sqrt d+1}4=\frac 12\\\frac {\sqrt d}4=\frac 34\\d=9$$

Comment: But having $l$ different than 1, would not that affect the result. or the scaling of the space won't have any impact?

Comment: It won't change the result of the space dimension.  All the linear dimensions are multiplied by $l$, so the first display equation would have a factor $l$ in each term.  We can then divide that out.

Comment: Yeah true, I just saw it too now. Still but confused how did you derive the distance between the corner and the center of the corner ball

Comment: The center is at a distance $\frac 14$ from the face in each of $d$ dimensions.  We use the $d$ dimensional Pythagorean theorem to say the square of the distance is $d$ times $(\frac 14)^2$

Comment: Do you have maybe then the theorem for the general case for applying Pythagorean in n dimensions ?

Comment: Nice. i like the solution. thank you again. I just need to read about the general case of Pythagorean theorem

Comment: It is just that the square of the distance between two points is the sum of the squares of the distances in each dimension, as all the dimensions are perpendicular to each other.  Play with it in 3D and it extends to all higher dimensions just the same.